# Clicking the hyperlinks for installed windows updates does not show the relevant web page associated with them

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

Clicking the hyperlinks for installed windows updates does not show the relevant web page associated with them.

A website should appear in my web browser when I click the name of an installed windows update giving more information about it.

Why doesn't it? How can I fix it?

[image: windows update installed windows updates on windows 10]

Comment: Can you access those websites using a browser? Try this one for KB4601050: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/february-9-2021-kb4601050-cumulative-update-for-net-framework-3-5-and-4-8-for-windows-10-version-2004-windows-server-version-2004-windows-10-version-20h2-and-windows-server-version-20h2-7d61f856-72ce-7f4c-7e43-76f8aadf2aca

Comment: Yes I can access those websites using a web browser if I click a hyperlink from an existing web page or type it in.

Comment: When did you notice this functionality didn't work?  What I can tell you, it's not a change with 20H2, so it's probably a unique configuration with your system

Comment: It started not working from yesterday or the day before.

Comment: @desbest - I would temporarily uninstall `KB5001649` `KB5000802`, if it's an update and not some other configuration to blame, uninstalling those updates should restore the functionality.

Comment: It's started working today. If I had to guess what happened, I would say that Windows executed a Known Issue Rollback. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/known-issue-rollback-helping-you-keep-windows-devices-protected/ba-p/2176831